# Branding of Eclipse view icons

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, branding

It is possible to change the branding of an Eclipse RCP application with an Eclipse "product". For example, the application icons, splash screen and about box can be changed.

**But is it possible to change the icons of other things with some sort of branding mechanism?**

It would be of interest to change to icons of the following things:

- Views (most important for me!)
- Editors
- Different kinds of resources (for example, in *Project Explorer* view)
- Toolbar buttons

If it is not possible to change these with some build in branding mechanism, is there any work around? Can this be done programmatically with reasonable effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to locate all brand specific icons to a branding plugin. The icons can then be changed by switching only the branding plugin.

To do this all icons paths must be set to icons in the branding plugin.

This can be achieved using the platform URI scheme in the `plugin.xml` file. For example:

```xml
<view>
    ...
          icon="platform:/plugin/com.app.branding/icons/icon.png"
</view>
```

Setting icons with platform URI:s is described the answer to this question:

[How can I reference an icon from a plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587664/eclipse-rcp-how-can-i-reference-an-icon-from-a-plugin)